# Is there a database on internet for LTspice models?

Tags: ltspice

LTSpice doesn't have many components as default. One has to download the spesific model component and integrate it. Is there a website where I can look for it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I do not now if there is something like a database.

But I got most of my models from either the ltspice yahoo group (https://groups.yahoo.com/neo/groups/LTspice/info)

Or from Farnell they have a spice model for most analog parts.

You have to create a login to download this models for both pages.

I personally did not find better solutions yet...

Comment: The link is no longer active. The new one is at [groups.io](https://groups.io/g/LTspice/).

Answer (score 2):

Site “[LTwiki.org](http://ltwiki.org/index.php5?title=Components_Library_and_Circuits)” contains a lot of models and a lot of useful information on said models.